# Laravel Builder could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Intento actualizar dos tablas **Medidor** y **Ordeninstalacion**, método edit recibe el ID de la orden de instalación, con lo cual se supone obtengo el numero de medidor, en realidad si hago **dd($idmedidor);** se muestra el numero, pero cuando trato de obtener el **Medidor** con el método find pasándole el id, obtengo el siguiente error.

> [2017-05-24 17:47:56] local.INFO: Orden instalada [2017-05-24
>   17:47:56] local.CRITICAL: Error apiControllerr 0 |
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/juntaAgua/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php
>   |Object of class Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder could not be
>   converted to string

**Controlador**

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $idmedidor = DB::table('Medidor')
        ->select(
            'Medidor.idmedidor')
        ->join('orden_instalacion', 'Medidor.orden_instalacion_idorden_instalacion', '=',
            'orden_instalacion.idorden_instalacion')
        ->where('orden_instalacion.idorden_instalacion', '=', $id)->get();

        try {
            DB::beginTransaction();

            $orden = OrdenInstalacion::find($id);
            $orden->estado = 1;
            $orden->fecha_instalacion = Carbon::now();
            $orden->update();
            Log::info("Orden instalada");

            $medidor = Medidor::find($idmedidor);
            $medidor->fecha_instalacion = Carbon::now();
            $medidor->estado = 1;
            $medidor->update();

            Log::info("medidor instalado");
            DB::commit();

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            Log::critical("Error apiControllerr {$e->getCode()} | {$e->getFile()} |{$e->getMessage()} ");
            DB::rollback();
        }
    return redirect::to('api');
}
```

Comment: ¿puedes mostrarnos exactamente lo que muestra `dd($idmedidor);`?

Comment: **dd($idmedidor);** =  `array:1 [
  0 => {#297
    +"idmedidor": 4
  }
] ` _  _ _ y return **$idmedidor;** `[{"idmedidor":4}]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teniendo en cuenta que estás buscando solo un registro, deberías usar el método `first()` en vez de `get()` y obtener la propiedad o campo respectivo, en este caso `idmedidor`:

```
$idmedidor = DB::table('Medidor')
    ->select('Medidor.idmedidor')
    ->join('orden_instalacion', 'Medidor.orden_instalacion_idorden_instalacion', '=', 'orden_instalacion.idorden_instalacion')
    ->where('orden_instalacion.idorden_instalacion', '=', $id)
    ->first()
    ->idmedidor;
```